# JavaScript identify object differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose there are 2 JS objects as follows:

```js
var object1 = {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 104, 5: 105, 6: 106};
var object2 = {0: 100, 1: 103, 2: 105};
```

object1 contains all acceptable values that can be used for Item IDs.  object2 contains Item IDs have been used already in the database.  How can the two objects be compared to create a third object that contains the Item IDs that have not been used yet?  The Item IDs that have not been used yet will be made into options for a drop down box.

I would rather not convert the objects to arrays to figure this out.  The desired outcome for this example is:

```
var result  = {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 104, 3: 106};
```

Comment: Those aren't jQuery objects. Do you mean JavaScript objects or do you *really* have jQuery objects and this is a simplification?

Comment: On the surface this appears to be a trivial JS issue. What am I missing?

Comment: Updated post to say JS instead of jQuery.  I have not found any good threads that address this problem...thus the creation of this post.

Comment: *"I would rather not convert the objects to arrays to figure this out"*: why not? The way you have your properties, is really what Arrays are good at. Why complicate your life?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would NOT use arrays, but here is a somewhat hacky solution to get you an Object in the end:

```
var arrObj2 = Object.values(object2);
var result = {};
Object.values(object1).filter(function(item) { return arrObj2.indexOf(item) === -1;})
      .forEach(function(item,index) {result[index] = item;});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You choose property names as Arrays would choose them for you, so it is quite odd that you want to stick with plain objects.

Here is how you can do it in one assignment, using a Set for quick lookup, and `Object.values` and `Object.assign` to switch between arrays and plain objects:

```js
var object1 = {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 104, 5: 105, 6: 106};
var object2 = {0: 100, 1: 103, 2: 105};

var a = Object.assign({}, Object.values(object1).filter(function (val) {
    return !this.has(val);
}, new Set(Object.values(object2))));

console.log(a);
```

If you would work with arrays, you could skip those calls to `Object.assign` and `Object.values`, and just do this:

```js
var arr1 = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];
var arr2 = [100, 103, 105];

var a = arr1.filter(function (val) {
    return !this.has(val);
}, new Set(arr2));

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object1 = {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 104, 5: 105, 6: 106};
var object2 = {0: 100, 1: 103, 2: 105};
//var result  = {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 104, 3: 106};
var i,
    ii,
    iii = 0,
    result = {};
for(i in object1){
  for(ii in object2){
    if(object1[i] == object2[ii]){
      break;
    }
  }
  if(object1[i] != object2[ii]){
    result[iii] = object1[i];
    iii+=1;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```